# how to delete 2 alias entries from keystore?

Tags: keytool

I have imported multiple certificates(with alias name) into `pc.keystore`. I want to delete 2 aliases (mydomain and ourdomain) entries from the keystore.

I know we can delete one entry from keystore using alias like:

```
keytool -delete -alias mydomain -keystore pc.keystore
```

But i want to delete two aliases (mydomain and ourdomain) entries from `pc.keystore`. Is there any option to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 54):

Is there a reason you can't do this?

```
keytool -delete -alias mydomain -keystore pc.keystore
keytool -delete -alias ourdomain -keystore pc.keystore
```

Comment: yes we can do but before delete i have to check the key store are exit or not

Comment: what do you mean "check the ks are exit or not" ?

Comment: is there any option to check both in one command because in my case 2 alias may vary in future. it may increase so its better to have in one command.

Comment: To avoid password prompt use the following, but beware that your pass will be stored in the bash_history which is insecure:  keytool -delete -noprompt -alias mydomain -keystore pc.keystore -storepass xxx

Answer (score 5):

It can be done in one command as well:

```
keytool -delete -alias mydomain -alias ourdomain -keystore pc.keystore
```

Comment: Sorry but I tried this and it didn't work. What happens is that `ourdomain` will be deleted but `mydomain` will stay. Refer to documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_delete

Answer (score 2):

```
keytool -delete -alias  name_of_certificate -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

`name_of_certificate` is the alias name that you want to delete from yout keystore

after `-keystore` the path is path to your `jks/keystore` place